# Compile Mac OS X SpriteKit applications to Windows or Linux

Tags: sprite-kit

Is there a way to make windows or linux applications in Xcode using the SpriteKit framework? I know that you can make OS X applications, but is there some sort of plugin for Xcode that compiles your OS X SpriteKit game to windows/linux executable files?

Comment: I really doubt it. It's meant to be iOS and Mac OS only

Comment: Your probably right hamobi, But there is a lot of apps for android thats written on objective-c using Xcode like sword and sorcery for example

Comment: You would need a third party library and I do not know of any for computer operating systems (there are of course some for mobile OS). Even then there would be performance drops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Spritekit is Cocoa only. Cocoa only runs on Apple owned platforms.

Consider unity for cross platform game development.

Comment: Well the reason why i switched to Xcode was because I dident like unity.. Anyway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Successful apps built specifically for android or Java tend to be "ported" or rewritten for the other platforms. Some gaming platforms like cocos2d have very similar API and so are much easier to port across platforms.